# How many levels of research are there for each enemy in Bioshock?

Tags: bioshock

Is it possible to know how many levels of research there are and what level I'm at? I see big letters (A, B, C) in red, but I understood that it was the quality of the picture (centered, enemy action, distance).

For example, with the "Spider Splicers", I finished the first level of research (I've filled the progress bar once). However, if I take a picture again, the progress bar restarts! So I guess there are several levels of research?

**How do you know how many levels there are and at what level I am?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are **five** levels of research for each 'creature' in the game.  I'm not sure if there's a way to know what level you're currently at.  Once you've completed all of the levels for a specific creature type, your camera won't accept photos of those creatures anymore.

A bit more about [researching](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Research_Camera), from the Bioshock Wiki:

> The Research Camera does no damage
> itself, but it is a deadly addition to
> the arsenal. It is equipped the same
> way as a weapon, and uses film to take
> pictures that unlock biological
> weaknesses and hidden secrets through
> research of every Splicer, security
> device, and Big Daddy.
>
> In each tree,
> there are **five** levels of research that
> require increasingly more photos to
> complete. On the first, third, and
> fifth levels of completed research, a
> permanent damage boost is applied
> against the researched enemy type. The
> second and fourth levels of completed
> research yield various Gene Tonics and
> other bonuses that are extremely
> useful. Little Sisters are the
> exception, as a permanent increase to
> health and EVE is given for each
> completed level of research.
>
> The Damage Research tonic increases
> effectiveness of damage bonuses from
> research. The Research Camera cannot
> be upgraded.